# validation (xhtml 1.0 transitional) element 'video' is not supported - Error occured when I add the video in my website.

Tags: html

I am using VS-2010 for development of my website. I want to add the video in my website.
When I add the below code I got the error "validation (xhtml 1.0 transitional) element 'video' is not supported".

```
<video width="320" height="240" controls>
  <source src="movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <source src="movie.ogg" type="video/ogg">
  Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

suggest me something...

Comment: The video tag is HTML5. You're using an XHTML 4 doctype

Answer (score 1):

The `video` element is not valid in [XHTML 1.0](http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/), only in [HTML5](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/) drafts, so the message is correct. In general, however, do not trust messages about validity unless you get them from a validator, and even then, caution is advised. (HTML5 is work in progress, and HTML5 validation is experimental.)

You can use the “More Options” feature at http://validator.w3.org and select “HTML5” there to see whether your document validates as HTML5. You can also replace the doctype string at the start of your document by

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

to make validators treat it as HTML5 by default.